# Can we add new module in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Can we add new module in Orchard CMS?

I need to implement ticketing system (a user can create a ticket and an admin will assign that ticket to a workflow).

Will Orchard allow us to add a new ASP.NET module?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard will allow you to create a new Module in an existing Orchard as well as Modifying existing Modules.

See [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/04/22/create-orchard-module-in-a-separate-project.aspx) for more info.